# How to avoide Circual dependency in different Apps in Django 1.10

Tags: django-models

I have 2 different apps eng and person.
eng app have 2 models
1. Task
2. Project
and person app have 2 models 
1. Case
2. Case Result

**Case Result** have **Project** as foreign key, but now I want **Case Result** as foreign key in **Task** but it giving error.
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: qa.0001_initial, engineering.0001_initial

I have tried lazy relation but it not work in different apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid circular

```
# Comment out any imports
# from app1.models import Project

class CaseResult(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey("app1.Project")
```